# Battery capacity dropped from 97% to 30%. Is it ubuntu's problem?

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery, msi

I have MSI laptop (**CX61 2QC**). I have purchased it recently (about 1 month ago). I have made a installed ubuntu installed in it. Yesterday when I was using it the battery capacity was showing 97 %. Today I woke up and when I booted my laptop the battery capacity was down to 30% and it is discharging very fast. Energy design is 48.8Wh and Energy when when full has dropped from 47Wh to 13.9Wh. From 97% to 30% is a huge drop. Is there some bug in ubuntu **LTS 14.04** or my battery is dying?  Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no problem with Ubuntu, Because it displays only the information what it gets from the battery.

It means that your battery was dying out soon.(99%)

Battery sensors may-be sending wrong Information.

Comment: I think you were right about the battery sensors  sending wrong information. I removed the battery , then placed it back and now it is showing the correct reading and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your battery status by typing `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` in the terminal.

The output should look like this:

```
native-path:          BAT0
vendor:               SANYO
model:                42T4694
serial:               1159
power supply:         yes
updated:              Fr 22 Jan 2016 12:20:15 CET (8 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
  present:             yes
  rechargeable:        yes
  state:               discharging
  energy:              35,96 Wh
  energy-empty:        0 Wh
  energy-full:         38,19 Wh
  energy-full-design:  93,24 Wh
  energy-rate:         12,748 W
  voltage:             12,377 V
  time to empty:       2,8 hours
  percentage:          94%
  capacity:            40,9588%
  technology:          lithium-ion
History (charge):
  1453461555    94,000  discharging
History (rate):
  1453461615    12,748  discharging
  1453461585    16,446  discharging
  1453461555    15,564  discharging
  1453461525    14,941  discharging
```

The `energy-full` shows the rest capacity, and the `capacity` shows it in percentage. You could use this as an indicator if your battery is dying.

And since it is not a brand new laptop, you could try to recalibrate your battery.

Unplug your laptop from the power supply.

`cat /dev/zero > /dev/null` only uses one core, but should drain your battery fast enough.

Keep it running until it shuts down, don't use any hibernation.

When it's off, press the power button and hit the key for your BIOS, and keep it in the BIOS until it goes off. Now charge your battery until it is fully charged, you can use your laptop as normal, but do not unplug it.

This will recalibrate the electronics in your battery. I got about 5% more capacity with that method.